# why doesn't json schema validate definitions defined in required attribute

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a json schema that validates an object depending on its type. It picks the right definition, however, it doesn't validate the required attributes in the selected definition. Here is the json schema i am trying:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

    "definitions": {
        "literal": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "raw": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["raw"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "identifier": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["name"],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },

    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "enum": ["Literal"]
                },
                "content": { "$ref": "#/definitions/literal" }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "type": {
                    "enum": ["Identifier"]
                },
                "content": { "$ref": "#/definitions/identifier" }
            }
        }
    ],
    "required": ["type"]
};
```

the following schema is valid, even tho its missing the "raw" property:
`{ "type" : "Literal" }`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no keyword `content` in JSON Schema spec.

Once you have asserted `"type":"object"` in root schema, there is no need to do it again in subschema.

In order to combine object `type` enumerated value with associated extended definition, you need `allOf` keyword.

Also in definitions if you use `"additionalProperties": false` you have to list all properties of the object (see `"type": {}`). For previously defined/validated properties you can just use permissive schema: `{}` or `true`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "literal": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {},
        "raw": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["raw"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "identifier": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {},
        "name": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["name"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },

  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "enum": ["Literal"]
            }
          }
        },
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/literal"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "enum": ["Identifier"]
            }
          }
        },
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/identifier" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "required": ["type"]
}
```

Comment: Curious to know where `"content"` came from. OP can you explain?

Comment: thanks, this seem to have fixed it :) @Relequestual i probably copy pasted the "content" attribute from an invalid example. was digging into this issue couple hours so the final result as it was copied here, had multiple revisions